# MBProgressHUD wont show

Tags: objective-c, ios, mbprogresshud

i am playing around with MBProgressHUD. the worflow in the viewcontroller (tableview) goes like that:

1) IBAction gets called to switch between 2 different tables
2.1) function `reloadAllMonth` gets called (initializes an array with the data for the new table)
2.2) MBProgressHUD *HUD should be displayed
3) reloadAllMonth is finished
4) HUD should disappear

my current code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

        //sparing you the code that determins where the tap occured

        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        [self reloadAllMonth];
        allMonthIsActive = YES;
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

// some other code table reload etc.
}
```

what happens:

-> function touchesbegan gets called
-> nothing happens for 3-4 seconds (loading time)
-> new table pops up

**question:** why does the HUD not show up? where did i go wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have both show and hide in the same thread, this is what I would do:

```
-(void)reloadStuff
{
    [self reloadAllMonth];
    allMonthIsActive = YES;
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    isLoading = NO;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //sparing you the code that determins where the tap occured

    if (isLoading)
        return;
    isLoading = YES;
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doStuff) withObject:nil];
}
```

Also you can remove the ivar HUD, you are not using it.

And don't forget to initialize isLoading in viewDidLoad to NO:

```
isLoading = NO;
```

Good luck!

Comment: i changed my code to your suggestion but it doesnt change anything. the HUD still wont show. i updated the questions code to the new one.

Comment: this was my absolut first idea and code. the problem is: the reloadAllMonth method is then performed in the backgroundthread. thus the main thread runs on and starts drawing the tableview. the tableview needs the data i load in reloadAllMonth. so the table starts drawing before its data is availabe thus the app crashes =)

Comment: If you make sure that the data you need is nil from the start then the table will be empty and the app will not crash. Then when you finish loading reloadAllMonth you simply call reloadData again and the table will be display your data.

Comment: ok. this was really helping me. i had to call table.reloadData with the hud selector to get the right effect.
it works quite well now. i have one problem though. if i tap the app somewhere while the progressHUD is spinning, the table does finish reloading, displays the right way, but then i cant interact with the app any more. do you have a clue why?

Comment: You can define a ivar BOOL to make sure that you don't try to reload more than 1 time. I have edited my answer to reflect this. the BOOL is called isLoading.

Comment: i thought i had that covered with allMonthIsActive, but i see the difference now with the return cause =) thanks a million times. it works now =) you've really earned that accept & upvote for taking you time multiple times to edit and rethink :)

Comment: hm i do have a follow up.
the action is in a tabbar application. when i press another tab while the MBProgressHUD is showing, somehow the app freezes. the wheel turns infinitly long and i cant interact anymore, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are u fetching anything from the server ? 
If so please check whether u are passing synchronous request or  asynchronous . Asynchronous requests are the best to follow . 
Handle MBProgressBar in this way .

```
  [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           //Any UI updates should be made here .
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        });
```